# Как сделать динамический метод в модели ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

У меня есть ассоциативный массив записей c таблицей `Company`

```
[
#<CompaniesRole:0x00005625a9fe0220 id: 1, company_id: 1, role: "product", permission: "create">, 
#<CompaniesRole:0x00005625a9fcfce0 id: 2, company_id: 1, role: "order", permission: "update">
]
```

Надо сделать в модели `CompaniesRole`, что бы я смог вызвать в следующем формате:

```
 company.companies_roles.order 
 => #<CompaniesRole:0x00005625a9fcfce0 id: 2, company_id: 10, role: "order", permission: "can_update"
```

и мне вернуло только одну запись где у роли есть поле с role = 'order'.
Вариант с исользованием where и find напрямую, к примеру `company.companies_roles.where(role: 'order')`не подходит.

> Возможно ли использовать define_method для решения этой задачи и какой
>   будет вид?

Comment: А чем не устраивает скоуп с передаваемым именем роли? Не очень понятен вопрос, точнее ваши ограничения

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, что ответили. Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Поле ролей у меня представленно как enum, я использовал [gem enumerize](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) и добавил к энуму scope: :shallow. Получилось именно то что я хотел - Когда вызываешь значение енума напрямую на классе.